# CustomErrors don't work when on the defaultRedirect page

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-error-pages

the tag looks like this:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/RSRTerror.aspx" />
```

redirect works fine when i'm on any other page like:

```
http://mysite.com/hello.aspx?idx=somethingWrong
```

the above redirects to the error page with no problem.

however when i am on:

```
http://mysite.com/RSRTerror.aspx?aspxerrorpath='"--></style></script><script>netsparker(0x0023B6)</script>
```

it gives me the following:

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

the error i see when i turn the customErrors off is:

A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client

how do i handle it?

if i set ValidateRequest="false" on the Errorpage, will it allow more vulnerabilities to go through?